# Accessing contact info of Incoming calls/sms

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to confirm if it is allowed to access the Contact Info of Incoming Calls/SMS  programmatically. Are developers allowed to access and retrieve the contact info of incoming calls or sms. Is there any API available for this.
Thanks

Taimur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access Contact info via a published API.  But you can't access any info about an incoming SMS or call to use to look up in Contacts, at least in any app running on a stock OS and that complies with the SDK agreement.  The app is in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for what you want.

Comment: is there any alternate way of doing this. can i access contact numbers. i really need to do it.

Comment: They probably don't let you access the incoming number for privacy reasons.  Someone could write an app which collects all incoming calls from a user and publish it.  Total privacy snafu